# Skype Installation error on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, skype

I want to install latest version of skype on my laptop with ubuntu 14.04 version. But when I install skype from latest deb file I receive following error

```
Wrong architecture "amd64"
```

My system information is given below

```
rizwan@rizwan-ThinkPad-E520:/$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2330M CPU @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x25
cpu MHz     : 825.687
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx lahf_lm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts
bugs        :
bogomips    : 4390.13
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2330M CPU @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x25
cpu MHz     : 816.406
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx lahf_lm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts
bugs        :
bogomips    : 4390.13
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2330M CPU @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x25
cpu MHz     : 856.195
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx lahf_lm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts
bugs        :
bogomips    : 4390.13
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2330M CPU @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x25
cpu MHz     : 886.531
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx lahf_lm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts
bugs        :
bogomips    : 4390.13
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: `uname -m` outputs `x86_64` for you I suppose? *How* did you try to install Skype? Download the `.deb` (not the `.rpm`!) from [here](https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/) and install it with `sudo apt install /PATH/TO/skypeforlinux-64.deb`.

Answer (score 0):

What Operating system are you using? I think it's 32-bit operating system. Check with `uname -r` command. `x86-64` means 64-bit. `x86` means 32-bit.

A 32-bit OS works fine with 64-bit CPU. But while a 32-bit OS is installed a `amd64` i.e. 64-bit architecture program can't be executed.

Unfortunately, **Skype doesn't have a 32-bit version** anymore. So, use their web client or upgrade your system to 64-bit OS.